# CheckBox Values In HTML

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to create a site settings page with some checkboxes. If the checkbox is 'ON' a HTML element has a certain value, else it would be something else. But for some reason every checkbox keeps returning the value "on" in JavaScript. Please help.
My HTML:

```
<p>Click this checkbox</p>
<input type='checkbox' id='theBOX' checked='checked'>
<button onclick='theFunction'>Apply Changes</button>
<!-- Div that has to be toggled -->
<p id='TXT'></p>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function theFunction() {
  var valueOfCheckBox = document.getElementById('theBOX').value;

  if (valueOfCheckBox == 'on') {
  document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'ON';
  } else { 
  document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML += 'OFF';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues :

1 - You forgot the parentheses on the js function call :

```
<button onclick='theFunction()'>Apply Changes</button>
```

2 - When you set your js var with the value, or we dont need it. Just put this :

`var valueOfCheckBox = document.getElementById('theBOX');`

3 - Then to know wether it is check or not, use the js `.checked` property as following :

```
if (valueOfCheckBox.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'ON';
  } else { 
    document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML += 'OFF';
  }
```

Finally, your code should look like this :

```
<p>Click this checkbox</p>
<input type='checkbox' id='theBOX' checked='checked'>
<button onclick='theFunction()'>Apply Changes</button>
<!-- Div that has to be toggled -->
<p id='TXT'></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function theFunction() {
  var valueOfCheckBox = document.getElementById('theBOX');
  if (valueOfCheckBox.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'ON';
  } else { 
    document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML += 'OFF';
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

your check boxes are checked by default. remove `checked=checked` from check box input

```
<input type='checkbox' id='theBOX'>
```

and yes you have to change the Javascript function to check whether check box has been checked or not

you can get the valueOfCheckBox to be true if the check box is checked otherwise it will be false

```
  var valueOfCheckBox = document.getElementById('theBOX').checked;

function theFunction() {
  var valueOfCheckBox = document.getElementById('theBOX').checked;

  if (valueOfCheckBox) {
    document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'ON';
  } else { 
    document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML += 'OFF';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the 'checked' attribute from your input tag

```
<input type='checkbox' id='theBOX' >
```

```js
function theFunction() {
  var valueOfCheckBox = document.getElementById('theBOX').value;

  if (valueOfCheckBox == 'on') {
  document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'ON';
  } else { 
  document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML += 'OFF';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click this checkbox</p>
<input type='checkbox' id='theBOX'>
<button onclick='theFunction'>Apply Changes</button>
<!-- Div that has to be toggled -->
<p id='TXT'></p>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it does not work. Did you try?

Comment: @Mamun you have not removed the checked attribute from your code, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .checked property. This property returns true if the checkbox is checked by default, otherwise it returns false.
If you want by default checked on input box, just add checked attribute in input tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="theBOX" checked>
```

Hope this may help you.

```
<head>
<script>
    function theFunction() {
        var valueOfCheckBox = document.getElementById('theBOX').checked;

        if (valueOfCheckBox) {
            document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'ON';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'OFF';
        }
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Click this checkbox</p>
<input type='checkbox' id='theBOX'>
<button onclick='theFunction()'>Apply Changes</button>
<!-- Div that has to be toggled -->
<p id='TXT'></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```js
function theFunction() {
var valueOfCheckBox = document.getElementById('theBOX');

if (valueOfCheckBox.checked) {
document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'ON';
 } else { 
document.getElementById('TXT').innerHTML = 'OFF';
 }
 }
```

```html
<p>Click this checkbox</p>
<input type='checkbox' id='theBOX' checked />
<button onclick='theFunction()'>Apply Changes</button>
<!-- Div that has to be toggled -->
<p id='TXT'></p>
```

I would recommend you to use`<label for="checkbox">Click this checkbox</label>` instead of `<p>Click this checkbox</p>`.